# Solve the equation $\overline{PC}^2 + 2 \overline{PD}^2 + 2\overline{AP}^2 = 7$ under some assumptions on those points.

Tags: trigonometry

Take $D$ and $C$ two points respectively on the tangents in $A$ and $B$ of a semicircle af diameter $AB$ with $\overline{AB} = 2$. Moreover chose $C$ and $D$ such that $\overline{AD} = \overline{CB} =1$ and take $P$ a point on the semicircle.

Once set $P\hat{A}B = x$, solve the equation
$$\overline{PC}^2 + 2 \overline{PD}^2 + 2\overline{AP}^2 = 7.$$

Honestly I'm a little rusted in such exercises, I know I should use the cosine theorem or the chord theorem, but I can't make a step further.

> Any hint on how to express $\overline{PC}, \overline{PD}, \overline{AP}$ in term of $x$ would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Please draw a picture, and insert it in the question, it is a minimal step for problems involving a geometrical setting, it would also confirm an own effort to solve the issue, and in the same time offer context for the problem. Assume we are in a cartesian coordinate system, with $O$, the mid point of $AB$ as origin, and with the $x$-axis $AOB$. Which are the coordinates of the given points? We know the "inscribed" angle $\widehat{PAB}=x$, what is the measure of the angle at center $\widehat{POB}$? Which are the coordinates of $P$ now? Which equation is obtained in $x$ now?

Comment: Oh, could it be that $P\hat O B = 2x$?

Comment: Sure, now the coordinates of $P$ are transparent... feel free to solve, and insert an own answer to the question!

Comment: thank you so much! Excelent hint.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint that @dan_fulea gave we have that $P\hat O B$ is $2x$, thus once choosen $O$ as origin of a coordinate system we have
$$ A = (-1,0) \quad C = (1,1) \quad D = (-1,1) \quad P = (\cos(2x),\sin(2x))$$
and as a consequence we can evaluate
$$ PC^2 = \big(\cos(2x) -1\big)^2 + \big(\sin(2x) -1)\big)^2 \\
PD^2 = \big(\cos(2x) +1)\big)^2 + (\sin(2x) -1\big)^2 \\
AP^2 = \big(\cos(2x) + 1\big)^2 + \sin^2(2x)$$